# Create dynamic table in Stimulsoft Reports.JS

Tags: javascript, angular, stimulsoft

I have a stored procedure in the SQL server that takes two date arguments, does some calculations, and returns a table that the number of columns and rows are dynamic, due to the provided date arguments. My question is how can I simply show this **dynamic table** in **Stimulsoft Reports.JS**?

I can send the arguments to SQL and am able to receive the result in the execution query page, but I can't create a table to make its columns in the runtime. as far as I know, columns are static and I must receive the columns first to design the table in the design-time and I can't create that table since its columns are dynamic and they depend on the provided arguments by user.
I'm using Angular 7 npm package for the report.

Thank you.